# Rendering website in different viewports [ Mobile, Tablet, Desktop ] on Desktop Browser window

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I was building an app similar to **WIX** that enables user to create website easily. On Top, there are these three icons (Desktop, Mobile, Tablet) for users to select and view their website in that respective viewport.

I was curious, what's the best way to go about doing this?

I have looked up and found that iFrames are one way to achieve this. I was building this app with react and used 'react-frame-component' package to wrap my component with an iframe. Still pretty far away from the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If your media queries are based to screen dimension and not to dpi or other device specific features you can simply wrap your entire website preview in a div with the desired measures:

e.g.:

```
.wrapper.mobile{
  width:100%;
  max-width:480px; /* or whatever */
}

.wrapper.tablet{
  width:100%;
  max-width:720px; /* or whatever */
}

.wrapper.desktop{
  width:100%;
}
```

Then with simple js function append the right class to wrapper based on user choose.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is store the current device type somewhere in the state. For example, in the redux store and conditionally load CSS or a class based on the state.

This is easier if you are using some sort of css in js for eg. styled-jsx components. You can then load them based on simple conditional rendering.

Eg.

```
if(this.state.deviceType === "mobile"){
    let styling = styles.mobile;
}
```

And the use the styling variable in the component

Comment: I did think about this approach.